# How to implement a class holding connections to website, each in separate thread simultaneously?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit in java as a "browser" for accessing my website.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. log into my website under different usernames at the same time
2. keep all connections alive and for each user do different authorized requests to the website simultaneously

How to approach a working solution?

As of now I have classes "pages" (Selenium style) that represent separate pages on the website and they are all sub-classes of parent Page class.
Page class sets in its default constructor static connection that all the sub-classes inherit. This connection is later used for accessing other urls/links on the website..

```java
public abstract class Page {
    protected Logger logger;
    protected static Connection connection;

    public Page(){
        connection = Connection.getConnection();
        this.logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

The Connection class (singleton) returns the single instance and has method to login to the website along with methods to access other urls/link on the website

```java
public class Connection {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionManager.class);
    private static Connection connection;
    private CookieManager cookieManager;
    private WebClient browser;

    private Connection() {
        browser = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        cookieManager = browser.getCookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = new Connection();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void login(String url, String username, String password) {
        // load url, get form, fill form, login.... etc
    }

.. other methods
}
```

Than I use it like this:

```java
Connection connection = Connection.getConnection();
connection.login("http://somesite", "username", "password");
SomePage somePage = new SomePage(); // subclass of Page
somePage.clickSomeLink();
etc..
```

Now if I run it in separate threads the static Connection is shared in between all the other threads that use it right?

So how to make it work simultaneously?

..I want to use the connection's methods and thus share that connection between all the pages, but only for one thread.. now if this is bad design and could be done better I'd be really happy to hear a better approach.

Comment: You probably don't want to share the `WebClient` between users--if it stores cookies then they are likely to cause problems where the sessions interfere with each other. Also you'd have to do extra synchronisation if `WebClient` isn't thread-safe to ensure the aren't other problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yep as I replied in the answer, I would like to have one WebClient per one session one thread, just don't know ho to share it between the pages without endlessly creating new instances of it..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't share the instance of your class `Connection` between threads, because the incapsulated object `WebClient` is not thread safe, see the javadocs for [WebClient](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html):

> Note: a WebClient instance is not thread safe. It is intended to be
>   used from a single thread.

The [`CookieManager`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.html) is thread safe, but why whould you want to share cookies between your users?

Base line is, you should not make your `Connection` class a singleton, but instead create a new one for each user/thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, CookieManager is my bad, it wont be shared between users. 
As for the WebClient, thats exactly what I'm looking for, use one instance per thread, so I don't have to worry about thread safety.
But how to pass the Connection(WebClient) to the other pages?
Now if I change it from singleton to public contructor, each new page is going to create a new instance of Connection thus WebClient. How to solve that?

Comment: Then don't create a connection inside the page, just create a connection and pass it as an argument constructor to all of the instances of the pages for a single user.

Comment: Oh, how did I not think of this before, that's just what I needed. Thanks a lot!